# How can find the key of the first non-NULL entry in a array?

Tags: php, arrays, list

Considering an array in which values are added irregularly. E.g:

```
$array = [ 'Foo', NULL, 'Bar', 'Baaz', NULL, NULL, 'Another Foo' ];
```

How could I find the key of the first `NULL`entry **without explicitly iterating** (for, foreach, while...) -AND- operating an array as an array (i.e. no sorcery involving things not related to an array)?

In the example above it would be `1`, the index of the second entry.

My goal is to enhance a **List** I have. Lists are like arrays but they stay sequentially indexed (i.e. 1,2,3,4) all the time, after adding or removing, that can be manipulated directly (which *could* cause irregular NULLs)

By knowing what's the key of the first `NULL` entry, I can add items to a specific index or not, and when not, I insert items in "free spots"

> Re-indexing before adding is not an option

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do I have a code not working? Can you be certain I have a code that doesn't work? Can you see beyond a non-existent problem, read and interpret the post? Thank you <_<

Comment: StackOverflow is not a "code this for me" service.

Comment: What do you mean "without iterating"? `array_search()` for instance [still iterates](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/9cf87aa1965504b1cd9dc595a3c6af418a416cfc/ext/standard/array.c#L1577) behind the scenes.

Comment: Yeah, I should've been more clear with that, I'll edit. @yivi, just... stop embarrassing yourself, man

Comment: I'm not embarrassed at all. Thank for worrying. This question is kinda embarrassing though. Still, very happy that you got what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to correct your array, it has missing `'`

```
$array = [ 'Foo', NULL, 'Bar', 'Baaz', NULL, NULL, 'Another Foo' ];
```

You can use php function

```
echo array_search(NULL,$array);
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know of this function. It solves the problem as currently presented but unfortunately, I won't be able to use it as the enhancement I had in mind. BTW, I didn't downvote, must have been someone from this toxic community that downvote and leave for the simple fact they can downvote and leave. Thank you for your time :)